# WSO2 Identity Server Session Management

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Can you please elaborate how the sessions are managed in the WSO2IS. How are the incoming tokens handled, sessions are expired , session protection is done etc.

If you can please point me a link where i can read those information.

Comment: you can get some information regarding the session management referring this blog http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/10/15/how-to-configure-session-time-out-in-wso2-identity-server-wso2is/

Comment: What do you meant by `incoming tokens handling` ? Do you meant the validation of access and refresh tokens ?